# Installing pjproject for Asterisk

Tags: linux, centos, asterisk

I'm installing Asterisk 12 on CentOS 6.5. I'm trying to install the pjproject using [this article](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Building+and+Installing+pjproject). Everything looks fine up through step 6. I see all the .so files when I run the `ldconfig`, but when I run `make menuselect` for asterisk, all of the res_pjsip modules have the "XXX" next to them.

The configure script I used was

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/lib64/ --enable-shared
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You need do same prefix when installing both app.

Comment: Yeah, I use `./configure --libdir=/usr/lib64` when configuring asterisk. Still no go.

Comment: you have use same prefix... like prefix=/usr/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Asterisk can't find the `libpjproject.pc` file which pjproject installs to `/usr/lib64/lib/pkgconfig`. I was pretty sure this was wrong, so I moved it from that location to `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig` then set

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

before running the `./configure` for asterisk. This shows the modules installed now.

[More info on troubleshooting](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Building+and+Installing+pjproject#BuildingandInstallingpjproject-Asteriskfailstodetectpjprojectlibraries)

Comment: I think you have read my answer. if use configure with SAME PREFIX!!! all files will be on correct places. libdir and prefix is NOT same.

Comment: Right, but it had nothing to do with configuring asterisk. So libdir was correct. pjproject installs to the wrong dir on 64bit os. Sorry, but your answer did not help.

Comment: Not right. libdir is not enought. You also need give path to packageconfig files. I don't know why you use libdir. You CAN use librdir, but if so you have do manual configure this package when do configure in asterisk. see ./configure --help